# Reason why $P(X = k) = 0$ but $P( k_1 \leq X \leq k_2) \neq 0$ for continous random variable $X$

Tags: probability, statistics

This might be too easy (or almost trivial) for many out here, but i am having troubles with this. 
I know for any continous random variable $X$, $P(X = k) = 0$, however the probability that $X$ falls in $[k_1,k_2]$ is not necessarily zero, where $k_1 < k_2$.

I've been using this notion since high school and collage, but I never seem to grasp the idea. Am i being too superficial or is it okay to pause and wonder a bit here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes exactly .. Feel free to edit the question to modify ($k_1 < k_2$ and "can be non-zero") @Robert Isreal

Comment: It depends on how you're using the terminology. To me, choosing a number uniformly at random from $[0,1]$ yields a continuous random variable $X$, but one for which $P(2\le X\le 3) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fundamental difference in the way probabilities are defined
for discrete and continuous random variables.

**Discrete.** The support of a discrete random variable is a finite or
countable set of points. By a table, a formula, or a graph the probability
for each point is specified. For example, consider the number $X$ of Heads
in $n = 20$ tosses of a fair coin, so that $X \sim Binom(20, 1/2).$
The support is the integers from 0 through 20, and the formula
$$P(X = k) = {n \choose k}(1/2)^k,$$
for $k = 0, 1, \dots, 20$ specifies the probability for each point in the
support. Thus $P(X = 15) = 0.01478577,$ as computed in R statistical software.

```
dbinom(15, 20, .5)
## 0.01478577
```

If you want the probability of an "interval," then you need to sum the probabilities of all of the points that lie in the interval. For example,
$$P(13 \le X \le 16) = P(X=13)+P(X=14)+P(X=15)+P(X=16) = 0.1302996,$$
computed as:

```
sum(dbinom(13:16, 20, .5))
## 0.1302996
```

For discrete distributions, intervals have probabilities only in terms of the
probabilities of the individual points they contain.

**Continuous.** By contrast, the distribution of a continuous random variable
is defined in terms of a density function. One might say that heights (in inches) of the
men in a particular population are distributed as the random variable
$Y \sim Norm(\mu = 69, \sigma = 3.5),$ and we might represent its density
function as $f(y).$

Probabilities of intervals are defined in terms of the area under the density function within the particular interval in question. For example, 
$$P(57 < Y \leq 70) = \int_{57}^{70} f(y)\,dy = 0.6121481.$$
computed (by 'numerical integration') as

```
diff(pnorm(c(57,60), 69, 3.5))
## 0.6121481
```

or approximated by standardizing and referring to a printed table of 
values of the standard normal CDF. (Numerical integration is necessary
for normal distributions because it is not possible to express a normal CDF
in 'closed' mathematical form.)

The probabilities
$P(57 \le Y \le 70)$ and $P(57 < Y < 70)$ are the same, because the
area of a boundary line is 0.

[image]

If you ask for the probability a person chosen at random from this population is 68 inches tall, then technically you might write $P(Y = 68) = 0.$ But that indicates he is
*exactly* $68.000\dots$ inches tall, which is not feasible to measure.
You might say, "But that is ridiculous. I *know* a guy who is 68" tall."
What you may really mean is that you know someone who is between 67.5" and 68.5"
tall. *Then* you have an interval and you can find its probability (even if
small): $P(67.5 < Y \le 68.5) = 0.1090839.$

```
diff(pnorm(c(67.5,68.5), 69, 3.5))
## 0.1090839
```

[image]

For a continuous random variable, the way to make sense of a "point" is to
ask for the probability of the *interval* you actually intended. (Or if
you actually intended a point measured with perfect accuracy, then
0 probability can be taken as a reflection of the impossibility of doing that.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.